# What is the significance of the song played at the end of Tangerines (2013)?

Tags: soundtrack, credits, tangerines

In the Georgian-Estonian film [*Tangerines*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2991224/) (2013) at the end of the film as it rolls into the credits what is the song that is being played? It sounds like a rock/alternative song. What was the context and significance of the song?

Comment: The context was the credits. I don't know if songs chosen for credits necessarily have any particular significance other than aesthetic.

Comment: The song that plays right before the credits. I don't want to give spoilers but I would imagine there has to be some meaning the the song.

Comment: Possibly, but remember that music is art and art is usually highly personal. It may have simply been a song that they felt fit well--regardless of any particular meaning. I think the only way to answer this would be to find a quote from someone involved with the decision making process for the soundtrack. (Which may very well exist.)

Comment: I will search....Do you know the name of the song by chance?

Comment: I haven't seen the film. There are a few songs listed on the IMDB page, though. Did you check those?

Comment: Well, I know the name of the song, but I couldn't tell you what significance it has because the lyrics are in Georgian. In any case, it's *Qagaldis Navi* by [Irakli Charkviani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irakli_Charkviani); you can hear it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvhbf_dMolI).

Comment: Yes you were correct that is the song and it was on the imdb page. I looked on the imdb page when the film first came out and I don't remember seeing that song on there. I will do some research on the lyrics and hopefully find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after finding some English translations of the song it has become quite clear of the significance of the song.

> From my understanding the gist of the song is about coming home to a loved one and the fact that the person singing can't stop thinking about them. “I will swim over the sea, Don’t listen to anybody else saying I won’t come, I will come back to you, I will return.” --So it no surprise Nika had a cassette with this song on it given he is in a war. Like DA said in the comments it was probably also put there for aesthetic purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The song was popular among fighters back in the war in 1992, Irakli Charkviani’s Qavagadi Navi (A Paper Boat) – a promise to return no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

I found a complete English translation of this song (and great interview with the director) which has been haunting me ever since I saw this film a few weeks ago:

I want to be with you again
Even when I fight, I am with you in my dreams
I´ll be back, I´ll sail back on a paper ship
I´ll come back to you from over the seas
Don´t believe it if they say I won´t come back
I will come back to you

— Irakli Charkviani, “A Paper Boat,” 1992

from:  http://www.kinocaviar.com/tangerines.php

Comment: You might want to elaborate in which way this answers the question asked in order to make this a proper answer rather than a comment.